# CMAKE - Add default command line arguments to a cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I am creating and building a `c++` project using `cmake` from scratch.
The executable requires **command line arguments**.
I am specifying them in `Visual studio`.
**Is it possible to specify them by default when cmake builds the project (in my `CmakeLists.txt` for example) ?**
So that I (or others) won't need to specify these arguments each time I build the project for the first time (I would want to just run the project without worrying about that but still can change them in visual studio of course if needed) ?

[image]

Comment: The principle with CMake is that it will regenerate the solution if something changes, so no, you must not manually change the solution. Still don't understand what the link is with command line arguments for an executable though.

Comment: Well I have to push arguments to the executable (basically a port number) and I am doing that in Visual studio after cmake has already built the project (from debugging options). I want to have a default port number that would be defined when cmake builds the project. When I get to visual studio, I will just have to run the project. You understand me better ? @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: What I mean is that what I want to achieve is like defining a default startup project in the solution (Instead of ALL_BUILD) by putting this in `CmakeLists.txt` : `set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT projectname)`

Comment: You can add `config.h` file (like [here](https://github.com/BartekkPL/bvh-parser/blob/master/cmake/config.h.in)) and then add some additional instructions to `CMakeLists.txt` file (like [here](https://github.com/BartekkPL/bvh-parser/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L179-L191)) and then use info from `config.h` file as default.

Comment: Are you talking about arguments for the debugger to pass onto your executable?

Comment: @StoryTeller Check picture

Comment: See my now undeleted answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using CMake 3.13 and above you can add the [`VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS.html#prop_tgt:VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS) property to your executable target in order specify those arguments.

Comment: This is the line to add to `CmakeLists.txt` in case someone needs that : set_target_properties(TargetName PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS "arg1 arg2 ... argN")